# TypeError: Parent.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'

Tags: python

```py
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def printName(self):
        print(self.name)


class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, name):
        Parent.__init__(name)

bob = Child('Bob')
bob.printName()
```

It's working with `super().__init__(name)` but not with the class name, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work since `Parent.__init__` is defined to take two arguments: `self` and `name`, and you're passing just a single argument to it. Thus, if you want to call it like that, you need to use `Parent.__init__(self, name)`. But there really is no point, and you should instead just use `super().__init__(name)`, as you already know.

Answer (score 0):

The init() method always requires the self parameter, which is a reference to the object itself. Without the self parameter, the init() method would not have access to the object's attributes and would not be able to initialize them properly. The fix can be found here.

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def printName(self):
        print(self.name)


class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, name):
        Parent.__init__(self, name)

bob = Child('Bob')
bob.printName()
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because `Parent.__init__()` always requires `self`.

However, `super().__init__()` does not require `self` because it implicitly finds the `self` by MRO (Method Resolution Order). You can see the order using `Class.__mro__`, as follows:

```py
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def printName(self):
        print(self.name)


class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, name):
        Parent.__init__(self, name)

bob = Child('Bob')
print(Child.__mro__)
# (<class '__main__.Child'>, <class '__main__.Parent'>, <class 'object'>)
```

Here, if you use `super.__init__(name)` instead of `Parent.__init(self, name)`, it will find `Parent` by the order.

For more information: see https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super